# Configuring Hibernate Entity Listeners for only group of entities

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

As per https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/, I would like to configure entity listeners for post insert/update/delete events for my group of entities. I do not want these listeners for all entities in my application. So I created an abstract class for group of entities and implemented onPostUpdate/onPostInsert methods. But I wont be able to configure this abstract listener class for the integrator part as it would require only concrete listener. Any recommendation of the solution ?

**ConfigHibernateEntity**

```
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostDeleteEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostDeleteEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostInsertEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostInsertEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;


public abstract class ConfigHibernateEntity  extends HibernateEntity implements PostUpdateEventListener, PostInsertEventListener, PostDeleteEventListener{


    // public static final ConfigHibernateEntity INSTANCE =  new ConfigHibernateEntity();

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

        final Object entity = event.getEntity();

        System.out.println("On post update method");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

        final Object entity = event.getEntity();

        System.out.println("On post insert method");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent event) {

        final Object entity = event.getEntity();

        System.out.println("On post delete method");

    }
}
```

**EventListenerIntegrator :**

```
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;


public class EventListenerIntegrator implements Integrator {

   @Override
   public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor 
         sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

      EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = 
            serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_INSERT)
                     .appendListener(new ConfigHibernateEntity());

      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE)
      .appendListener(new ConfigHibernateEntity());


      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_DELETE)
      .appendListener(new ConfigHibernateEntity());


   }

   @Override
   public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
         SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

   }
}
```

**CustomEntity1 Class:**

```
public class CustomEntity1 extends ConfigHibernateEntity  {

//

}
```

**CustomEntity2 Class :**

```
public class CustomEntity2 extends HibernateEntity  {

//

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing the listeners in ConfigHibernateEntity itself create separate listener class and check if the entity is instance of ConfigHibernateEntity,

```
public class ConfigHibernateEntityListener implements PostUpdateEventListener,
PostInsertEventListener, PostDeleteEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2607908089881583295L;

private final Predicate<Object> checkInstanceOfConfigHibernateEntity =
    event -> event instanceof ConfigHibernateEntity;

@Override
public void onPostUpdate(final PostUpdateEvent event) {

    final Object entity = event.getEntity();
    if (checkInstanceOfConfigHibernateEntity.test(entity)) {
        System.out.println("On post update method");
    }

}

@Override
public void onPostInsert(final PostInsertEvent event) {

    final Object entity = event.getEntity();
    if (checkInstanceOfConfigHibernateEntity.test(entity)) {
        System.out.println("On post insert method");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(final EntityPersister persister) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPostDelete(final PostDeleteEvent event) {

    final Object entity = event.getEntity();
    if (checkInstanceOfConfigHibernateEntity.test(entity)) {
        System.out.println("On post delete method");
    }

}
```

And the `ConfigHibernateEntity` can be like below,

```
/**
 * Marker class for adding configure entity listeners for 
 * post/insert/update/delete
 */
 public class ConfigHibernateEntity {
 }
```